# PL/SQL: convert explicit cursor to ref cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can I convert an explicit cursor into a ref cursor? I was thinking of something like:

```
declare
  cursor c is
  select x from tab;

  rc sys_refcursor;

begin
  open c;
  rc:=c;
  close c;
end;
/
```

I would like to use the ref coursor as an input parameter for a procedure.

I know I can always do it like this:

```
OPEN rc FOR select x from tab;
```

But I'm in the process of refactoring some old code an I would have liked to keep the explicit cursor definitions just for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Why do you need to convert one to the other? Can you provide a [MCVE] showing how this would be used?

Comment: Opening a cursor for a cursor is not allowed till Oracle 11g. Not sure if this can work on Oracle 12c as 12c has many such features.

Comment: This is not currently possible, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, opening a sys_refcursor for another cursor is not allowed till Oracle 11g. As you are trying to do something which demands use of sys_refcursor, once way could be like below:

Create a type

```
CREATE TYPE va IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/
```

Block:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c
   IS
      SELECT employee_id FROM employee;

   rc    SYS_REFCURSOR;
   var   va;
BEGIN
   OPEN c;

   FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO var;

   CLOSE c;

   OPEN rc FOR SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE (var);
END;
/
```

You would see here that at the end am using again a `SELECT` statement for `ref_cursor`. It's just like if you dont want to use usual way, i used an alternative way.

Comment: This works but renames columns ATTR_n. See [this flow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946595/convert-explicit-cursor-to-ref-cursor-without-renaming-columns-attr-n). Ideas?

Comment: I sorted my problem. I had to `SELECT ATTR_1 As COLUMN_VALUE FROM` when I tried a similar thing.

Comment: @XING Can this same syntax/process be used on a Table that is defined as `var   t_employees;` where the TYPE is defined as `TYPE t_employees IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE`?  This answer uses a NUMBER TABLE and using SQL is able to select from the number table var `OPEN rc FOR SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE (var);`.  When var is defined as a complex type I am not able to OPEN my Ref Cursor.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @CodeNovice Untill 11g you cannot use a `Type` defined under the scope of `PLSQL` block in a `select` statement inside the block. In `12c` this is possible.