# Convert explicit cursor to ref cursor without renaming columns ATTR_n

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want run some code over a cursor but also report the contents of the cursor so I can have a sneak preview of what it is about to do. The preview is a query table in Excel and wants a `REF CURSOR` for the`{Call}` syntax. In PL/SQL the natural syntax for coding against is an explicit cursor. With help from @XING in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075885/pl-sql-convert-explicit-cursor-to-ref-cursor) I developed this package.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MyPackage
AS

  -- This could be a complex query with many paramters and columns
  CURSOR curMyCursor(pParam1 VARCHAR2) IS
  SELECT pParam1 hello, 'ColNames' goodbye
  FROM DUAL;

  -- I could just let GiveMyCursor return a SYS_REFCURSOR but wanted to try max clues
  TYPE refMyCursor IS REF CURSOR RETURN curMyCursor%ROWTYPE;
  -- The TABLE function in GiveMyCursor needs the row type to be externalized
  TYPE typMyCursor IS TABLE OF curMyCursor%ROWTYPE;

  PROCEDURE RunMyCursor(pParam1 IN VARCHAR2);
  PROCEDURE GiveMyCursor(pCursor OUT refMyCursor, pParam1 IN VARCHAR2);

END MyPackage;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MyPackage
AS

  PROCEDURE RunMyCursor(pParam1 IN VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    FOR recMyCursor IN curMyCursor(pParam1) LOOP
      NULL; -- Do normal cursor loop processing
    END LOOP;
  END RunMyCursor;

  PROCEDURE GiveMyCursor(pCursor OUT refMyCursor, pParam1 IN VARCHAR2) IS
    tabMyCursor typMyCursor;
  BEGIN
    OPEN curMyCursor(pParam1);
    -- Load the entire contents of the cursor into memory and pray it fits
    FETCH curMyCursor BULK COLLECT INTO tabMyCursor;  
    CLOSE curMyCursor;

    -- PROBLEM: The TABLE function renames the columns ATTR_1, ATTR_2, etc
    OPEN pCursor FOR 
    SELECT ATTR_1 HELLO, ATTR_2 GOODBYE 
    FROM TABLE(tabMyCursor);
  END GiveMyCursor;

END MyPackage;
/
```

For my sneak preview I want to give the end user a simple table with filtering an sorting that they can refresh. Without duplicating the query, a simple Excel query table with a procedure that returns a `REF CURSOR` e.g. `{call MyPackage.GiveMyCursor('World')}` gives:

```
HELLO | GOODBYE
------+---------
World | ColNames
```

If I hadn't re-specified the column names in the `OPEN pCursor` I would have got

```
ATTR_1| ATTR_2
------+---------
World | ColNames
```

So `OPEN pCursor FOR SELECT *` would have allowed me enhance/fix my query with no other maintenance ramifications, but the end user would lose the column descriptions.

Is there some way in GiveMyCursor I can add some code to prevent having to re-specify all column names. Some built-in DBMS package I can interagate the cursor or one of the types to build a string or something to keep it generic?

My database is Oracle 12.1.0.1 SE.

Comment: You can parse the columns of a ref cursor using [dbms_sql.to_cursor_number](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68279) (example [here](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml)). However unless I am misunderstanding your requirement the problem is knowing the attributes of the collection type that you declared, but without hardcoding them again, to simplify maintenance. I suppose you could use `dbms_sql.to_cursor_number` to parse `select * from table(tabMyCursor)` but do you really need the column names anyway?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I've clarified may question as to why I need column names. `dbms_sql.to_cursor_number` needs an `OPEN`ed `REF CURSOR` passed in, but when the code with `SELECT *` gets to that point the column names have been lost.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear to me why do you require a second `REF CURSOR` as an `OUT` parameter, when the `curMyCursor`  itself could be passed.

In your code comment,

> -- Load the entire contents of the cursor into memory and pray it fits

are you probably assuming that storing the records in memory would yield better performance? As a matter of fact, When you use a  `CURSOR`, Oracle actually opens an unnamed work area that stores processing information. So, why not directly pass the first `CURSOR` and use it in the calling block?

Having said that, in your case, the statement

```
FETCH curMyCursor BULK COLLECT INTO tabMyCursor
```

doesn't do a column to column mapping, unless you have properly defined it while declaring the collection.

What you could do is, declare a `RECORD` with expected column data types.

```
 TYPE MyrecordType is RECORD 
(
 hello VARCHAR2(10),
 goodbye VARCHAR2(10)
 );
TYPE typMyCursor IS TABLE OF MyrecordType ;
```

instead of

```
TYPE typMyCursor IS TABLE OF curMyCursor%ROWTYPE;
```

Now, you will have proper names to all columns of the record elements in the collection. You should then be able to directly use `SELECT *` instead of specifying the elements.

```
OPEN pCursor FOR 
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE(tabMyCursor);
```

Comment: The problem with "directly pass the first `CURSOR`" is that the consumer is outside Oracle, in fact Excel. I have altered the question to show that. I'd love to be able to pass Excel an explicit cursor.

Comment: It works! I can now use `SELECT *` and keep my column names. The definition of the columns names are then kept in the package spec next to the cursor they come from. The down side is I have to continue to re-specify the column names and now also specify all the column types. One forward, two back.

This does progress my understanding the problem. It was not with the `TABLE` function in `OPEN pCursor` but `curMyCursor%ROWTYPE` in `TYPE refMyCursor` that was losing column names.